# How to create new record number in List Column

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-server

I've migrated the data from one application to SP2010.

In my SharePoint list the column name is Request No.(Number). In this column the last record number is 400. Now when I'm going to add a new record it should be 401. However, it's taking as 0.

So when I add any record, Request No (Field Type - Number) should increment. E.g., if current record is 400, then when I add a new record it should be 401.

Comment: How is the column incremented on the old application? Incrementing is not default behaviour, some sort of code or workflow must have been involved. Only ID auto increments, but that is SharePoint behaviour very hard to modify.

Answer (score 1):

simple quickfix. import 400 rows of excel data in your list.
then start importing from your other list. that way you have records that will start with the correct number.
after you have imported a few records you can delete your "dummy" data.

Comment: Record is already Imported from SharePoint List. For Column = Request No "Field Type = Number" I want if I add new record it should generate next number. I have try using calculated using some formula but not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check the field type is "Counter" or not(not just Number).

```
var ctx  = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('LibName');
var fields = list.get_fields();
var field = fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle('ColumnInternnalName');
ctx.load(field);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
  alert(field.get_typeAsString()); // should return "Counter"
},function(s,a){alert(a.get_message())});
```

if not, try to change the Type to counter then try to upload.

```
field.set_fieldTypeKind(SP.FieldType.counter);
field.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync((function(){
  alert(field.get_typeAsString());
},function(s,a){alert(a.get_message())})
```